# How do I change the value of a character with a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that receives an character and returns a digit.

Here's my code:

```
function get (char)  {
  if (char == "A"||"a") {
    return char = 5
  } else if (char == "B"||"b") {
    return char = 4
  } else if (char == "C"||"c") {
     return char = 3
  } else if (char == "D"||"d") {
     return char = 2
  } else if (char == "F"||"f") {
     return char = 0
  }
}
```

but anytime I run it against any character, it always returns 5.

Any help please.

Comment: You're testing the value `"a"` which is true in a boolean context. You need to compare it to char instead: `if (char == "A"|| char == "a") {`

Comment: You should make your character lowercase (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), and use a switch/case (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). This will make your code more readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: (The question I've flagged is about Python rather than Javascript, but the syntax differences between the languages shouldn't matter - that's still the exact same issue that is affecting this question.)

Answer (score 2):

Each test in a condition must be a complete test that can stand on its own. `char == "A"` is, but `"a"` isn't. The use of a logical operator such as `&&` and `||` doesn't change that.

Also, when you return, you only return a value, not an assignment.

The code must be:

```js
function get (char)  {
  if (char == "A"|| char == "a") {
    return 5;
  } else if (char == "B"|| char == "b") {
    return 4;
  } else if (char == "C"|| char == "c") {
     return 3;
  } else if (char == "D"|| char == "d") {
     return 2;
  } else if (char == "F"|| char == "f") {
     return 0;
  }
}

console.log(get("A"));
console.log(get("b"));
console.log(get("C"));
console.log(get("d"));
console.log(get("f"));
```

But, to make things simpler, it's customary to convert the input to either upper or lower case before testing and then you only have to test for the string and not the case:

```js
function get (char)  {
  char = char.toLowerCase();
  if (char == "a") {
    return 5;
  } else if (char == "b") {
    return 4;
  } else if (char == "c") {
     return 3;
  } else if (char == "d") {
     return 2;
  } else if (char == "f") {
     return 0;
  }
}

console.log(get("A"));
console.log(get("b"));
console.log(get("C"));
console.log(get("d"));
console.log(get("f"));
```

Or, if you are looking for a more compact way of getting this result that removes the need for `if/then` in the first place, you can simply return [the index position of the match in an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
let scores = ["f","","d","c","b","a"];
function get (char)  {
  return scores.indexOf(char.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(get("A"));
console.log(get("b"));
console.log(get("C"));
console.log(get("d"));
console.log(get("f"));
```

Answer (score 1):

inspired from **Scott Marcus** answser
 (it's just a minor "error" correction)

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```js
const scores = ['f','','d','c','b','a']

delete(scores[1])  // minor correction on Scott Marcus answer

const get=char=>scores.indexOf(char.toLowerCase())

console.log('A ->',get('A'));  // 5
console.log('b ->',get('b'));  // 4
console.log('C ->',get('C'));  // 3
console.log('d ->',get('d'));  // 2
console.log('f ->',get('f'));  // 0

console.log('empty string ->',get(''));  // -1 (actual Scott Marcus code return 1)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call what I did as having an "error". I would simply say that your code provides a "not found" flag of -1 (which is a good thing). ;)

Comment: Right, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code you want but if you want to parse a number, use `parseFloat/parseInt`:

```
function get (char) {
if (char == "A"||char=="a")
    return 5
else if (char == "B"||char=="b")
    return 4
else if (char == "C"||char=="c")
    return 3
else if (char == "D"||char=="d")
    return 2
else if (char == "F"||char=="f")
    return 0
else
    return -1
}
```

Comment: you forget  `return char = 4`

Answer (score -2):

```
 function get (char)  {
  if (char == "A"|| char == "a") {
    return char = 5
  } else if (char == "B"|| char =="b") {
    return char = 4
  } else if (char == "C"|| char =="c") {
     return char = 3
  } else if (char == "D"|| char == "d") {
     return char = 2
  } else if (char == "F"|| char == "f") {
     return char = 0
  }

  return char;
}
```

I made a similar error when encoding [paperio 3](https://paperio3.com)